# Unit tests root dir to take deployment items

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, mstest

How can I declare that the "root" folder for all deployment items are the .sln dir?

Seems like I work really hard with relative paths of deployment items

```
 [TestMethod]
        [DeploymentItem(@"..\..\..\MyTestFilesFolder\myFile.xml")]
        public void Test_bla{}
```

Given that "MyTestFilesFolder" is near my .sln file (solution folder) I'd like to have

```
 [TestMethod]
            [DeploymentItem(@"MyTestFilesFolder\myFile.xml")]
            public void Test_bla{}
```

How can this be achieved with tests of vs2013?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are not deploying the xml files with your unit tests. Go to the properties of the xml files and set the build action and to content and copy to output directory to copy always. Now the files are deployed to your test directory.

Comment: mmm - should I actually "add item" of this files? shoule I see them inside the IDE? I thought just to put them on disk and refer their folder path...

Comment: The xml files are part of your tests. I would recommend to add them to your project and source control. Without them your tests are useless.

Comment: you must add them to the project and set them to be copied to the output directory (as peer indicated) otherwise MSTest won't be able to find them and deploy them to the test location